# header file information necessary for .so files

Tags: java, shared-libraries, header-files

I understand that java does not have the concept of a header file like in C/C++.  Question is regarding creation of library files (.so or .a) for Java.  When we create the .so file, don't we need to provide the header file (definitions) information for the consumer of the .so file?  In java how do we do that?  If we provide the whole java source code, then the advantage of concealing the source code is gone.  Am I missing something here?  Can someone clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by "when we create the `.so` file?" Java doesn't normally _have_ `.so` files.  It doesn't use them in any way.

Comment: In normal Java programming environment, .class files are equivalent of .a's and .jar files are equivalent of .so's. Java compiler can retrieve symbols and class/method signatures from .class's and .jar's on its class-path for compiling your source code, then you don't need header files, full of source files, but just compiled files.